Filter with __contain__ with multiple conditions
I am trying to filter with __contains__ but with multiple conditions, however I am not getting the result I need
This is my code:
text = ['BAILE\nMADRID\nPRECIO\n15,20€\n','DANZA\nBARCELONA\nPRECIO\n13,50€\n','BACHATA']

result = [line for line in text if not line.__contains__(('MADRID\nPRECIO\n15') or ('BARCELONA\nPRECIO\n13')) ]
print(result)

The result you should get is:
['BACHATA']

but it takes me out:
Output:
['DANZA\nBARCELONA\nPRECIO\n13,50�\n', 'BACHATA']

If I use __contains__ only with one condition it does fine.
What an I doing wrong?

note you might be looking for regular expressions! https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

You shouldn't be doing a.__contains__(b), you should use b in a (which eventually ends up doing the same thing, but nicer).

This is due to how Python evaluates the or condition in your contains call. You need to explicitly check both conditions separately and combine them with or, like this:
text = ['BAILE\nMADRID\nPRECIO\n15,20€\n','DANZA\nBARCELONA\nPRECIO\n13,50€\n','BACHATA']

result = [line for line in text if not ('MADRID\nPRECIO\n15' in line or 'BARCELONA\nPRECIO\n13' in line)]
print(result)

Instead of using contains, it's more idiomatic to use the in operator in Python to check if a substring exists in a string.

Your logic was not expressed correctly, and you should be ORing the entire __contains__ expressions as follows:
text = ['BAILE\nMADRID\nPRECIO\n15,20€\n','DANZA\nBARCELONA\nPRECIO\n13,50€\n','BACHATA']

result = [line for line in text if not line.__contains__('MADRID\nPRECIO\n15') and not line.__contains__('BARCELONA\nPRECIO\n13') ]
print(result)  # ['BACHATA']

Note: To understand what your original logic was doing and why it was behaving that way, consider:
x = 'MADRID\nPRECIO\n15' or 'BARCELONA\nPRECIO\n13'
print(x)  # 'MADRID\nPRECIO\n15'

So your initial logic was effectively filtering on only the first string, but not the second.
